# Bash/Git - Prompt User for Password Issue

Tags: bash, git

I've made a bash script that automates a git commit to a remote. However, when it gets to the commit it doesn't pass the SSH key password prompt to the user, it just exits.

Here's the relevant part of the script!

```
set -e

[...]

read -p "Would you like to upload your app now? [y/n]: " -n 1 -r
echo    # (optional) move to a new line
if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    exit 1
fi

git add *
git commit -m "Commit (Automated)"
git push cloud master
```

Not really a shell script person, so any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: to clarify I want the user to be prompted to enter their password at "git push..."

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? I tested your code and it looks to be working fine.

Comment: Hello! I've got a local password on my SSH key and it's not prompting for that...just wondering if there's something I'm missing re sending the output (e.g. the password prompt) to the console :)

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! Well, I don't think your missing something. As I said, I just tested it. Anyways, you can try to add a ssh-agent to your currently running terminal and see if it will push then.

Comment: Thank you! Ok, I'll give that a go :D

Comment: Yay, worked it out! Looks like the "set -e" at the top of the script was seeing my git commit's "Everything is up to date" response as a failure and was exiting before the push :) Thanks for your help @mnestorov!

Comment: Glad it went good. I would suggest you update your question to include the `set -e` section of the code and then write-up an answer so that others might see it and know how to fix this in the future :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Looks like the "set -e" at the top of my script was the culprit. It saw the git commit commands "Everything is up-to-date" response as a command failure and exited. Removing it solved the issue :D